# Type conversion of an integer in prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to convert a negative integer value into positive value.

Eg:- input `-10`, output `10`.

How can I do this conversion in Prolog, is it possible to do?

Comment: `Y is -X.` Please consult a manual.

Comment: Or you could say `Y is abs(X)`. Not that different from changing sign in any other language.

Answer (score 1):

As @false pointed out, Prolog is (more or less) untyped.

In order to interpret a functor in a mathematical way, the `is` operator can be used.

Such operator resolves a syntax tree, like:

```
+(*(5,2),7)
```

Will be resolved to `5*2+7` thus `17`.

`+` here has no real binding to the addition, it is simply a functor that holds two other terms. Only the `is` operator will "interpret" it as addition.

Short answer:

```
minus(X,Y) :-
    Y is -X.
```

The `is` operator is not bidirectional. Thus `minus(X,-5)` will not be resolved. Only `minus(-5,X)`.